# Filter ActiveRecord by range of attribute values in has_many association

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Lets say I have Person which has_many toys. Then I have a Toy which has_many colors. What I'm trying to do in my Person#show method is filter the toys that contain a range of colors.

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :name
 has_many :toys
end

class Toy < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :size
 belongs_to :person
 has_many :colors
end

class Color < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :color
 belongs_to :toy
end
```

Then in my PersonController I want  to filter Toys be a range of colors.

```
class PersonController < ApplicationController
 def show
  @person = Person.find(params[:id])
  # Now I want to filter by toy colors that might be red or blue or purple or etc...
  # So when in my view I do @person.toys I know they only contain the filtered colors
  @person.toys.categories
 end
end
```

And help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Still actively learning Rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to go the DB approach you could do something like:

```
if params[:toy_colors].nil? 
  @toys = @person.toys
else
  colors = params[:toy_colors].split(',')
  # NOTE. You should obviously check that the colors array 
  # contains only expected colors to avoid any sql injection.
  @person.toys.joins(:colors).where('colors in ?', colors)
end
```

where the colors are passed in as a param eg.

```
http://localhost:3000/person/1?toy_colors=red,green
```